# Is there any difference in meaning between "a customer called" and "a customer called in"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Can you please tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *a customer called* and *a customer called in*? For example:

> Today one customer **called** and asked if we still had that tablet in stock.
>
> Today one customer **called in** and asked if we still had that tablet in stock.

I've tried to find an answer on the internet, but I haven't been able to find an answer. I've heard both in the context, so I suppose both are perfectly natural, right? I'd like to know what the *in* adds to the meaning.

Comment: **Called in**  is a phrasal verb which needs a  object.

Comment: It may be colloquial. "Called" may simply mean "called".  "Called in" may mean "called and confirmed".

Comment: @Dmytro O'Hope  Can you tell me in which sense you are using "called in".

Comment: To my British ears, _called_ can mean either 'made a telephone call' or 'paid a brief visit'. _Called in_ suggests the second meaning (came into the shop).

Comment: "call in" also have the meaning **to phone a place in order to give or get information** (as per Cambridge dictionary )

Comment: @Sam: I used in a sense of making a call.

Comment: Yes, i have given the answer.

Comment: "Called in is a phrasal verb which needs a object." Not to my ear - it means actually physically walked into the shop. 'Called' could be telephoned or walked in, but if the establishment uses both phrases as policy, then it's telephoned.

Comment: @Sam - That usage appears to be American. I gave my British understanding of the phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those verbs are correct and natural in your example, but the verbs "call" and "call in" are not the same.

"Call" means to make a phone call, to or by anyone or anything, for any purpose.

"Call in" means to make a phone call for any purpose other than a social one, usually to report or gather information. For this reason, we almost only "call in" to organizations. Like, if you're sick, you can call in and let your work know you won't be coming in. If a radio show accepts phone calls, you can call in to win a prize. If you've lost your credit card, you can call in and report it.

It's very rare to "call in" with friends or family. Nearly every call to someone you know has a social element to it. The only time you'd "call in" with family or friends is, for instance, if your father is in critical condition in hospital, and you call in with your mother every half hour to get an update.